# Sequence bounded and series diverges implies $R=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

There is an exercise in Lay's Real Analysis (8.3.7) which runs:

Suppose that a sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded but that the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.  Prove that the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum a_n x^n$ is equal to $1$.

Certainly, if we plug $x=1$ into the power series, we have a divergent series, so it's trivial that the radius of convergence $R\leq 1$.  I don't see how (in fact I don't even believe that) $R$ is forced to equal one.   I'm really hoping someone else has run into this exercise and can testify to it being misstated.  But if you can prove $R=1,$ fine.

Comment: Hint: if $|a_n| \le M$ for all $n$, then $\limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} \le \limsup_{n\to \infty} M^{1/n} \le 1$.

Comment: This is not misstated. The above result holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is bounded by a constant $M$. Then you have:

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |a_kx^k|$ $\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |Mx^k|$=$M\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |x^k|$. What is the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$?

Comment: Thanks. That does it.  There's a published solution which is completely wrong, so my spider senses went off and interfered with my thinking.

Comment: You're welcome.